# Software to emulate ARM on Windows

Tags: windows, virtualization, arm

I would like to emulate a few ARM images, but I just cannot find a tool for that. Is there something like VirtualBox to have an ARM virtual machine?

Comment: We were looking for something like this a few years back and couldn't find anything specific to the Windows Platform...  However, since then with all the cloud providers they are saying it's possible to spin up any device OS you want.

Answer (score 1):

yes, [QEMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU) can also emulate [ARM-platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU#ARM)!